# Managing Multiple AWS Accounts using EB deploy

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on two different projects for two different companies. Each of them gave me access to their AWS management console to deploy Ruby applications. I'm writing the code on my Mac OS/X.

I can't see where to change the configuration for the eb commands to point to the different accounts. I did `eb init`, but it seems to point to the same AWS account and creates the application and server instance on that account. Can someone please help or guide me to instructions when using two different AWS accounts for two different projects and trying to deploy using the eb command?

Comment: Can you show what happens when you run `eb init`?

Comment: When I ran eb init the first time it asked for app name, region, etc.  When I run it now it doesn't ask for it.  I assume it's stored in a config file, so it just looks there.  However, it didn't ask for my account information as to what IAM user to use.  It defaulted to my other project, so it ended up creating and deploying an application to the wrong AWS account.

Comment: Can you try running `printenv | grep "AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE"` from Terminal?

Comment: $ printenv | grep "AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE"  Nothing came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config data should be stored in `~/.aws/config`

You could maintain two different config files and simple swap them before deploying.  That would be easy if you work on one all day and then another all day, but if you are switching between the two throughout the day that could get confusing.

You could write a simple script to swap them prior to running eb init.

Since you listed Ruby as your language I found this neat write up of exactly what you need.
http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/10/19/managing-multiple-aws-account-credentials/

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is with "named profiles". Let's say for example that you have a work/default AWS account and also a personal AWS account.

Edit `~/.aws/credentials` to look like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = abcd1234KEY1
aws_secret_access_key = abcd1234SECRET1

[personal]
aws_access_key_id = efghij6789KEY2
aws_secret_access_key = efghij6789SECRET2
```

Then use `eb init --profile personal` to use your personal account.

AWS docs here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

Comment: I had a look at my configs and I have both an `.aws/config` and an `.aws/credentials`. Credentials contains a `[default]` section, whereas `config` contains a `[profile eb-cli]` section. Is the latter a hard-coded profile needed for the EB CLI (or did I create this at some point and forgot about giving it that name)? Anyway, this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html is relevant to also be able to use other non-EB AWS CLI:s.